# Proof or refute $n^n = \Omega(n!)$ with the help of Stirling's approximation

Tags: asymptotics, check-my-answer

I'm trying to proof/refute the following equation:

$$n^n = \Omega(n!)$$

Generally I would try to use Convergence Criteria and or [l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to solve such a problem.

$$\lim_{n\to \inf}{{f(n)}\over{g(n)}} = K$$

However, in this case $n!$ is somewhat of a party-stopper. I found [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which states that:

$$n! \approx \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2πn} $$

My idea was therefore:

$${n^n}\over{(\frac{n}{e})^n\sqrt{2πn}}$$
$${n^n}\over{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2πn}}$$
$${e^n}\over{\sqrt{2πn}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}{{e^2n}\over{2πn}} = \infty$$

$$ 0 < K \leq \infty $$

therefore the original equation is true.

Is that approach "ok", did I understand Stirling's approximation correctly?

Comment: You don't need Stirling here. You could simply use the definition of $n!$ to prove that $n^n \ge n \cdot n!$.

Comment: What you actually show is $n^n = \omega(n!)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stirling's approximation states that
$$ n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n. $$
This notation means that the ratio between the two sides tends to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity. For your purposes, we can simply write
$$ n! = \Theta(\sqrt{n} (n/e)^n). $$
Since $\sqrt{n} = o(e^n)$,
$$ n! = o(n^n). $$

If all you want to show $n! = O(n^n)$, then as Jukka mentions you can use the simple bound $n! \leq n^n$.